# Why does my code keep failing in codeblocks?

Tags: c, codeblocks

Here's the code I wrote.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    printf("hello World.");

    return 0;
}
```

This is the error message

Execution of '"C:\Users\Happy Birthday\Desktop\Coding\C++\C_C++ project\simple program.exe"' in 'C:\Users\Happy Birthday\Desktop\Coding\C++\C_C++ project' failed.|

Comment: What error message?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the code you posted. The problem must be with your configuration of Code::Blocks.

Comment: Without more details, we can't help you. Share the error message you get. The code you gave has nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Are you able to run the EXE outside Code::Blocks? You will need to open "cmd" to do this.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. I had to go to the location of the bin for MinGW, copy and paste its address into the Toolchain executables tab of the global compiler settings, as opposed to auto detecting it.